# How to search for a Word in a Register variable from a Shell script in Ansible?

Tags: shell, ansible, yaml

I am very new to ansible, i am writing a set of code where the result of a shell command goes to a Register variable, and in that variable, I need to find the keyword "happy". If the keyword is found, execute ANOTHER shell script. Shell command apparently outputs multiple different values, looks like a dictionary, it is not a straight forward string, so how do i find ONE word in the entire shell result.

My attempt:

```
- name: execute first task
 shell: /tmp/somescript
 register: myResult
- name: another shell script
  shell: /tmp/anotherscript
  when: "happy" in myResult.
```

This returns saying "condition was false", when the output DOES have happy in it per the output result.

Comment: Try `when: "'happy' in myResult.stdout"`

Comment: To add to @VladimirBotka advice, you should debug the content of your registered var to learn about its structure and content. You should also read the `shell` module documentation where all the returned fields are documented.

Comment: adding stdout worked :D @Zeitounator I did do debug as well, stdout narrowed down the result. Thank you so much guys :) .